# Wordpress multisite moving to another domain error

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have error with moving wordpress multisite to another domain

Error is like: just redirecting to old site or just "Database connection wasn't established"

What I did:

1. moved all files of site to new hosting
2. moved database to new hosting and rewrote old domain to new domain
3. Changed wp-config.php *

I move many times single(not multisite) wordpress sites, so I don't think the problem in steps 1 or/and 2, I think the problem in some settings in wp-config or .htaccess I tried to changes those settings but they don't work

Details:

Old domain was -> https://dearsystems.com

New domain is -> http://dearsystems.chornatastudio.com

My current wp-config.php:

```
<?php  
 // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'XXXXXX');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXXX');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXX');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');


define('AUTH_KEY',         'XXXXXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'XXXXXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'XXXXXXX');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'XXXXXXX');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'XXXXXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'XXXXXXX');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'XXXXXXX');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'XXXXXXX');

$table_prefix  = 'redacted_';

define('WPLANG', '');

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dearsystems.chornatastudio.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/inventory-software/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

# Disables all core updates. Added by SiteGround Autoupdate:
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

My .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /inventory-software/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# Added by Siteground Support Team
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterRemove 001566
</IfModule>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Also, may be it'll help: 
when I change this code line(which is below) in wp-config to old domain it reditrect me to old site:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'olddomain.com');
```

but when I write new domain - it shows me error "Error establishing a database connection"

Guys, MANY THANKS for any help and ideas

Comment: did you import the database also and also in the config setting you place the new domain database setting  ??

Comment: yes )) it is in my wp-config: define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'subdomain.newdomain.com');

It is screenshot when I replaced old domain strings in DB: http://joxi.ru/EA44DY9Cw6leQA

Comment: for now I have that error: "Error establishing a database connection"

Comment: also I noticed when I changed this line in wp-config: define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false); to "true" - it redirected me to that url: http://dearsystems.chornatastudio.com/inventory-software/wp-signup.php?new=dearsystems.chornatastudio.com
but it must have redirected me to that one: http://dearsystems.chornatastudio.com/inventory-software/

Comment: if you have a shell access, "wp-cli search-replace oldomain.com newdomaine.com --all-tables" is the way to go

Comment: can't I do this just using editor, for exapmle - notepad++  ?

Comment: Aso I have just tried to replace old domain in DB using special script  (https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and it still is not working  (error: "Error establishing a database connection")